run tests on github actions
i have problem when i try to run yamal file on github actions its stuck on : Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
i have this yaml file code :
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop

jobs:
  npm_install_and_run_tests:
    name: Install dependencies and run tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Node.js environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: "18"

      - name: Install backend dependencies
        run: npm --prefix ./backend/ install

      - name: Install frontend dependencies
        run: npm --prefix ./frontend/ install

      - name: Install Google Chrome
        run: sudo apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

      # - name: Start the backend
      #   run: npm --prefix ./backend/ start &

      # - name: Start the frontend
      #   run: npm --prefix ./frontend/ start &

      # - name: Wait for servers to be ready
      #   run: sleep 10

      - name: Run all tests
        run: npm --prefix ./frontend/ run navbarTest


and this the test code :
const { Builder, By, until, Browser } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const assert = require('assert');

describe("NavBar test", function () {
    this.timeout(100000);
    it("NavBar", async function () {

        let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser(Browser.CHROME).build();

        await driver.get('https://itstore-main-fe-omj2.onrender.com/');
        await driver.sleep(1000); // Add delay to observe page loading

        await driver.findElement(By.linkText('About')).click();
        await driver.sleep(1000);
        await driver.findElement(By.linkText('Product')).click();
        await driver.sleep(1000);
        await driver.findElement(By.linkText('Login')).click();
        await driver.sleep(1000)
        await driver.findElement(By.linkText('Register')).click();
        await driver.sleep(1000);
        await driver.findElement(By.linkText('Stav')).click();
        await driver.sleep(1000);
        await driver.findElement(By.linkText('Adar')).click();
        await driver.sleep(1000);
        await driver.findElement(By.linkText('Ido')).click();
        await driver.sleep(1000);
        await driver.findElement(By.className('cart')).click();
        await driver.sleep(1000);
        await driver.findElement(By.linkText('Home')).click();
        await driver.sleep(1000);

        const currentUrl = await driver.getCurrentUrl();
        assert.equal(currentUrl, 'https://itstore-main-fe-omj2.onrender.com/', 'Expected URL does not match actual URL');
        await driver.quit();

    });

});

when i deploy this on github i get this eror :
1) NavBar test
       NavBar:
     SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
      at Object.throwDecodedError (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:521:15)
      at parseHttpResponse (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:514:13)
      at Executor.execute (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:446:28)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

any one know why its not work ??? i try a lot of things and still its not open chrome i try also firefox and any other web browser please help me
i try to run on another web browser and another way to install chrome and i didnt get this please help me
